# What are an adviser's responsibilities?

Tags: career, soft-question

There seems to be a wide variance in what faculty members view as their responsibilities as a student’s adviser. I understand that some advisers go above and beyond what's expected and we can't hold everyone to their standards. I also understand that there is no one right method and two advisers with very different methods can be equally successful. However, it does seem useful to understand what we view as the baseline.

My question simply is: what are an adviser's role and responsibilities?

This question refers to both research as well as professional development (support, networking, job search, etc).

Comment: Dear anonymous: what do you actually expect to get out of this question? In other words, how would the answer to this question help *you* as an individual? In the current phrasing of the question it is not clear what the answer to the those questions are, and your question comes off as somewhat argumentative, which probably won't help your question stay open on MO.

Comment: @Willie thank you. I have attempted to soften the question. I know many students struggle at some point with these issues, yet there is very little written guidance on the topic. I am hopeful students may find answers to this question a useful resource in 1) knowing when to stand up for themself, as well as 2) managing unrealistic expectations.

Comment: I have several misgivings about this question, although I appreciate that it seems to be being asked in good faith. One in particular: roles and responsibilities and norms, either for students or for supervisors, vary from place to place (I am prejudicially assuming that the questioner is based in North America but I admit freely that this is mere speculation.)

Comment: I would much rather that a supervisor treats his or her students well and trains them to be good researchers in whatever way is most suited to the particular field of study, than to have a checklist of Roles and Responsibilities that they are supposed to tick off.

Comment: @Yemon, I don't think a statement of baseline roles and responsibilities is in conflict with a supervisor "treating his or her students well and training them to be good researchers in whatever way is most suited to the particular field". The question could just as well be: what does "treating his or her students well and training them to be good researchers" mean?

Comment: @anonymous: my answer to that reformulation: "it depends". Instructorship is not a form of customer service, just as an apprenticeship should not be a form of indentured servitude. And you still aren't saying whether this a German system, a Russian system, pure maths, applied maths, statistics...

Comment: I added the final vote to close because I think the responsibilities of an supervisor are precisely what Brian answered: "supervise a student's work on an MS Thesis or PhD Dissertation". How this happens is a very different question, and I wouldn't call that a responsibility of a supervisor. How this happens varies wildly from country to country, and depends on the ability of the student and the approach that the supervisor takes. To suggest it is the _responsibility_ of the supervisor to look for jobs for their students is pushing it a bit far, even if it is something that people do.

Comment: @anonymous I suggest opening a thread on http://tea.mathoverflow.net if you want to make a case for re-opening this question.

Comment: @David, “To suggest it is the responsibility of the supervisor to look for jobs” - who suggested that?

Comment: @Roberts: isn't the answer by Brian you quote somewhat of a joke? This question seems quite commensurate  with many others that have garnered interesting answers...

Comment: I thought this wqs meant as guidance for potential advisors, and as such I thought it useful, but it seems to have been a potential checklist for gripes from students?  Advisors I have known have done a lot for students, but some students seem to have thought the advisor was supposed to write the thesis, which is perhaps the only inappropriate role.

Comment: @Romeo: I fail to see how the answer by Brian Borchers is "somewhat of a joke". It may not be what some people want to hear, but that's another matter

Comment: @anonymous, to quote from the question, "...(support, networking, job search, etc)". I feel this question could be construed as constructing a list of expectations against which a supervisor can be measured. Such a measure will not be fair, given the differences in academic practice and tradition around the world and between institutions. To echo Yemon, there will be answers that do not fit with people's expectations, and this will descend into something MO is not designed for.

Comment: @David, you really do not see a difference between the question “what is the role of an advisor in the area professional development (support, networking, job search, etc)?”  and the suggestion “it is the responsibility of the supervisor to look for jobs for their students”? 

Comment: I can see there is a very fine distinction, but the point is moot, and immaterial to my decision to vote to close. If you want to convince people that this question is worth reopening, please discuss on meta.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion (and this certainly is in agreement with the practice in my department and university), the advisor's primary job is to supervise a student's work on an MS Thesis or PhD Dissertation.  At our institution, advisors are also responsible for making sure that students satisfy the specific course requirements for their degree.

I make it a point to discuss expectations with any student who asks me to be his/her advisor.  If the student has unreasonable expectations of me, I'll simply decline to advise that student.  If the student isn't willing to meet my expectations, then I'll also decline to advise that student.  Sometimes students decide after this conversation that they don't want me for an advisor.  The important point here is that both parties should understand how things will work before the student starts working with an advisor.

My expectations of students include:

1. I meet with my advisees regularly, most often once a week.  Each time that we meet I try to lay out specific work for the student to attempt during the next week.  I expect students to regularly achieve these short term goals- if a student is consistently unable to do so, I may terminate the advising relationship.
2. I expect students to write and edit their own manuscripts.  I am not happy if the drafts I'm given are filled with typos, spelling errors, or grammatical errors.  I want to spend our time together discussing mathematics at a higher level rather than copy editing text.
3. I expect students to produce research of publishable quality.  We plan out papers in advance, including who will be first author (usually I expect the student to take the lead in writing the paper and that they will be first author.)  I expect that papers will be submitted before a student defends his thesis or dissertation.

In return, I think that students can reasonably have some expectations of me:

1. I will be available to meet with them on a regular basis to discuss their project.
2. I will carefully review their drafts and provide substantive written comments.
3. I will be willing to write recommendation letters on their behalf.

I don't believe that the general "professional development" of graduate students is the particular responsibility of advisors.  Rather, I encourage my advisees to take advantage of 
available opportunities such as attending workshops and conferences, professional development programs offered through out graduate office, and our institution's writing center and disseration bootcamp.

My advice to any graduate student who is in the process of selecting an advisor is simple- discuss your expectations with the professor before filling out the paperwork to make him/her your advisor.

Comment: In pure mathematics, the first author designation is usually decided in a way that is somewhat unfair to the Rollbanks of the world, and much worse for the Zimmermans.  

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that system, but it's not as common in the areas of applied mathematics that I work in.  Since many of my papers have appeared in journals in disciplines outside of mathematics, I've adopted the more main stream culture, despite the fact that I'm blessed with a "B" name...  

Comment: Indeed, it would be even unhealthy if your students got all their professional development from you. The one good thing that advisors can do in that area is to keep informed about what opportunities are available, and to impress on student the importance of taking advantage of these opportunities.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from all the straightforward things that too many people don't do (meet regularly, help find a problem and suggest a plan of attack, help package partial progress into complete if modest theorems, etc) here's the big one:

Be honest if things are going badly!

Ask your student what their goals are. This basically means ask when do they expect to graduate and what kind of job do they want. If they are not on track, say so, because I bet you they didn't know that. Please do not tell them they're not ready at the last second, or write them a lukewarm letter while smiling to their face.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of this site. It is not to give you a forum for venting your anger or your frustration. If you have an axe to grind with your adviser, then I suggest that you
follow your own preaching and talk to him personally, rather than ranting here
anonymously.

Comment: I completely agree with @Alex. Furthermore, you (@Anonymous) would do well to remember that professors are generally hired more for their ability to prove theorems than for their social skills.


Comment: In my limited experience, one is discouraged from being blunt to students, presumably because everyone has their own favourite horror story of an advisor cutting their student of at the knees with criticism. So I don't really appreciate being told "if they are not on track, say so, because I bet you they didn't know that".

Comment: "Too many people don't do" - how many?

Comment: please note the author of the question and the author of this answer are not the same anonymous.

Comment: @anonymous, fair enough, though my comments to @Anonymous still stand

Comment: @anonymous We don't actually know that. They are both unregistered and anonymous. For all we know, it might be the same user. That's anonymity for you.

Comment: The more I re-read this, the more it feels like friendly advice "not to keep punching your wife in the face" ...